# Order being placed with an unexistent product

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, api, jpa

So, my code runs just fine, but I'm now aware of something that is not supposed to happen.
Whenever I create an order, with an unexisting product,like this :

```
{
"cartItems": [
    {
        "productName": "teste52",
        "quantity": 7
    }
],
"userEmail": "nemsei@gmail22.com"
}
```

it just creates the order like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"user": {
    "userId": 1,
    "userName": null,
    "email": "nemsei@gmail22.com"
},
"cartItems": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "productId": null,
        "productName": "teste52",
        "quantity": 7,
        "amount": 0.0
    }
],
"createdAt": "2023-01-06"
}
```

It is supposed to give an error, because the product with the name "teste52" doesn't exist but instead, it's creating that order, even without that product.
My order.java

```
package com.proj.my.model;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "myorder")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt"}, 
    allowGetters = true)  
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = ShoppingCart.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private List<ShoppingCart> cartItems;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, name = "createdAt")
    private LocalDate createdAt;

    public LocalDate getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDate createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(User user, LocalDate createdAt, List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.user = user;
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Order(int Id, LocalDate createdAt, List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
        this.createdAt =  createdAt;
        this.id = Id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setCustomer(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<ShoppingCart> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }
}
```

My orderService.java

```
package com.proj.my.service;

import com.proj.my.model.Order;
import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.model.ShoppingCart;
import com.proj.my.repository.OrderRepository;
import com.proj.my.repository.CloudProductRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class OrderService {

    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository;

    public OrderService(OrderRepository orderRepository, CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
        this.cloudProductRepository = cloudProductRepository;
    }

    public Order getOrderDetail(int orderId) {
        Optional<Order> order = this.orderRepository.findById(orderId);
        return order.isPresent() ? order.get() : null;
    }
    
   public List<Order> getAllOrderDetail(LocalDate yesterday, LocalDate today) {
        today = LocalDate.now();
        yesterday = today.minusDays(1);
        return orderRepository.findAllByCreatedAtBetween(yesterday, today);
    }

    public float getCartAmount(List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartList) {

        float totalCartAmount = 0f;
        float singleCartAmount = 0f;

        for (ShoppingCart cart : shoppingCartList) {

            String cloudProductName = cart.getProductName();
            Optional<CloudProduct> product = cloudProductRepository.findByProductName(cloudProductName);
            if (product.isPresent()) {
                CloudProduct cloudproduct = product.get();
                singleCartAmount = cart.getQuantity() * cloudproduct.getpriceInEuros();
                
                totalCartAmount = totalCartAmount + singleCartAmount;
                cart.setProductId(cloudproduct.getProductId());
                cart.setAmount(singleCartAmount);
                cloudProductRepository.save(cloudproduct);
            }
        }
        return totalCartAmount;
    }

    public Order saveOrder(Order order) {
        return orderRepository.save(order);
    }
}
```

My orderDTO.java

```
package com.proj.my.dto;

import com.proj.my.model.ShoppingCart;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderDTO {

    private List<ShoppingCart> cartItems;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userName;

    public OrderDTO() {
    }

    public OrderDTO(List<ShoppingCart> cartItems, String userEmail, String userName) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public List<ShoppingCart> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }

    public String getuserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setuserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public String getuserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setuserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderDTO{" +
                ", cartItems=" + cartItems +
                ", userEmail='" + userEmail + '\'' +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My orderController.java

```
package com.proj.my.controller;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.proj.my.dto.OrderDTO;
import com.proj.my.dto.ResponseOrderDTO;
import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.model.Order;
import com.proj.my.model.ShoppingCart;
import com.proj.my.model.User;
import com.proj.my.repository.CloudProductRepository;
import com.proj.my.service.CloudProductService;
import com.proj.my.service.OrderService;
import com.proj.my.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class OrderController {

    private OrderService orderService;
    private CloudProductService cloudProductService;
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository;


    public OrderController(OrderService orderService, CloudProductService cloudProductService, UserService userService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
        this.cloudProductService = cloudProductService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getOrder/{orderId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrderDetails(@PathVariable int orderId) {

        Order order = orderService.getOrderDetail(orderId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(order);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getOrders/{dataaa}")
    public List<Order> getAllOrderDetails(@PathVariable LocalDate dataaa) {
        return orderService.getAllOrderDetail(dataaa);
    }

    @PostMapping("/placeOrder")
    public ResponseEntity<String> placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderDTO orderDTO) {

        ResponseOrderDTO responseOrderDTO = new ResponseOrderDTO();
        List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartList = orderDTO.getCartItems();
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
        for (ShoppingCart cart : shoppingCartList) {
            String cloudProductName = cart.getProductName();
            Optional<CloudProduct> product = cloudProductRepository.findByProductName(cloudProductName);
            if (product.isPresent()){
                float amount = orderService.getCartAmount(orderDTO.getCartItems());

                User user = new User(orderDTO.getuserEmail());
                
                Integer userIdFromDb = userService.isUserPresent(user);

                if (userIdFromDb != null) {
                    user.setUserId(userIdFromDb);
                }else{
                    user = userService.createUser(user);
                }

                LocalDate createdAt = LocalDate.now(); 

                Order order = new Order(user, createdAt, orderDTO.getCartItems());

                order = orderService.saveOrder(order);

                responseOrderDTO.setAmount(amount);

                responseOrderDTO.setDate(com.proj.my.util.DateUtil.getCurrentDateTime());
                
                responseOrderDTO.setOrderId(order.getId());


                return new ResponseEntity<>("Created", HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            else{
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Can't", HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
        return null;

    }}
```

What can I do so that it gives an error instead of creating such order ?

Comment: Is ` if (product.isPresent()) {` working properly in orderService.java. Try logging the value before the `if` block

Comment: How ? Didn't understand, sorry

Comment: Where you check if product exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place where you are checking (and need to check) whether the product exists or not is in this block

```
public float getCartAmount(List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartList) {

        float totalCartAmount = 0f;
        float singleCartAmount = 0f;

        for (ShoppingCart cart : shoppingCartList) {

            String cloudProductName = cart.getProductName();
            Optional<CloudProduct> product = cloudProductRepository.findByProductName(cloudProductName);
            if (product.isPresent()) {
                CloudProduct cloudproduct = product.get();
                singleCartAmount = cart.getQuantity() * cloudproduct.getpriceInEuros();
                
                totalCartAmount = totalCartAmount + singleCartAmount;
                cart.setProductId(cloudproduct.getProductId());
                cart.setAmount(singleCartAmount);
                cloudProductRepository.save(cloudproduct);
            }
        }
        return totalCartAmount;
    }
```

Here you are fetching the `productId` and `amount` from the database.

If product doesn't exist, then `if (product.isPresent())`  block is not executed but the function `getCartAmount` **still returns normally** i.e. `cart.setProductId` and `cart.setAmount` are not executed and hence are null in your feed.

Try an else with this if block

```
else {
// throw error
}
```

Comment: Okay, yeah, I thought about that and managed to do it, it seems it is solved now !! Updated